# Finding Columns causing errors in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer, csv

I'm relatively new to Oracle SQL and trying to import CSVs using SQL Developer. I've been getting errors such as

> Insert failed for rows 1351 through 1400
>
> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Is there a way to determine the Columns that this error message concerns (?), so I can examine the values in the CSVs to see what is causing the error and how I should change the DDL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set the preview window higher, default is 100 rows.

[image]

Then we can validate more during the preview.

[image]

You can scroll the preview window's worth of data, and each column value for each row will get validated via the column definition in the data.

Or, set the import type to insert script, and run the script in a worksheet.

[image]